# How Would I Plot a Semi-Opaque Band of Values?

Tags: plotting

I need to plot a semi-opaque band from `y=1.95` to `y=2.05` (blue colored/shaded). How would I go about doing this? My range is from `x=0` to `x=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine it with a `Plot` use `Epilog`.

```
Plot[2.3 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
Epilog -> {Opacity[0.5], Blue, Rectangle[{0, 1.95}, {2, 2.05}]}]
```

[image]

Or you can simply use it with `Graphics`.

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Blue, Rectangle[{0, 1.95}, {2, 2.05}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Show:

```
Show[Plot[2.3Sin[x],{x,0,2},PlotStyle -> Red], 
Plot[2.05, {x,0,2}, Filling->1.95, PlotStyle->Opacity[0]]]]
```

[image]